# Using an unordered_set with shared_ptr keys

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, unordered-set

I am trying to use the following data collection in my program:

```
boost::unordered_set<boost::shared_ptr<Entity> > _entities;
```

I am using unordered_set because I want fast insertion and removal (by key, not iterator) of Entities.

My doubt is, if I implement the following two functions:

```
void addEntity(boost::shared_ptr<Entity> entity) {
    _entities.insert(entity);
}
void removeEntity(boost::shared_ptr<Entity> entity) {
    _entities.remove(entity);
}
```

When I try to remove the entity, will  the unordered_set find it? Because the shared_ptr that is stored inside the unordered_set is a copy of the shared_ptr that I am trying to use to remove the entity from the unordered_set if I call removeEntity().

What do I need to do for the unordered_set to find the Entity? Do I need to create a comparison function that checks the values of the shared_ptr's? But then won't the unordered_set slow down because its hash function uses the shared_ptr as hash? Will I need to create a hash function that uses the Entity as hash also?

Comment: Why `boost` in C++11 for those?

Comment: The compiler at my university probably is an outdated version of GCC that doesn't support C++11.

Comment: *The compiler at my university probably is an outdated version of GCC that doesn't support C++11.* This makes little sense. GCC supports C++11 since version 4.7. My university currently uses gcc 4.8.1. If this is really an issue, tell the sysadmins to upgrade to a more recent gcc compiler, because you want to use the current standard of C++.

Comment: Rather irrelevant discussion as it's a library addition not a language addition and they are essentially the same.

Comment: The purpose of an unordered_set is to guarantee uniqueness of the data in it, and to provide fast lookup and retrieval. Is the object itself going to be unique? Two equivalent objects are not the same object.

Comment: The idea of using the set is that the entities will be unique. If I use an unordered_set <Entity> and wanted to implement a getEntities function that returns the unordered_set and a getEntity function that returns a given set, how can I make sure that the set won't delete the Entities while I use an element that was returned?

Comment: Renato, you tagged this as C++11.  In error?

Comment: The implementation of boost's and std's version of both classes are similar,  but maybe, yes. I wanted to know what would happen if I used std's classes also, but I can remove it if c++11 tag is generating confusion.

Comment: @RenatoUtsch: If you don't want C++11 answers, don't tag C++11. Simple as that.

Comment: @Walter Informing the sysadmins to upgrade the compiler and they listening to us, doesn't happen all the time. Having said that, it could have been a mistake to tag this as C++11 question

Comment: There, removed it. Sorry for taking so long. And yeah, it is because I am not confident that they will upgrade that I am using boost.

Comment: @Jagannath Don't ask for an upgrade, but for an C++11 compiler. I would be very much surprised if nobody else at your university wants that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can use [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) in [`boost::unordered_set`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/unordered.html) (same applies to std version of these classes)

[`boost::unordered_set`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/unordered.html) uses [`boost::hash`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/hash.html) template function to generate keys for [`boost::unordered_set`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/unordered.html). This function is specialised for [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) to take underlying pointer into account.

Comment: when taking boost into account, will I be able to add or remove elements using the shared_ptr then?

Comment: boost has similiar implementation so it should work same as in std, I will update the answer

Comment: two shared pointers are the same if they contain the same underlying pointer. If you have two objects that are equivalent but not the same, they will be different.

Comment: the shared ptrs will be different, but they will point to the same entity.

Comment: Do you want to distinguish between particular objects, or their content, eg `string("abc") a1` and `string("abc") a2` are separate objects, but they are equivalent (`a1 == a2`)

Comment: I want to distinguish the Entity by object, not by the content. In your example I would distinguish the strings. They are not the same object.

Comment: Then you are safe to use shared_ptr in unordered_set

Comment: Thanks, I will use that then.

Answer (score -1):

Let me try to explain this if I got it right :-

boost::shared_ptr is implemented using reference counting mechanism. That means whenever you are passing it to some other let's say function you are just increasing reference count whereas when you delete it you are decreasing its reference count. When reference count is 0 then only that object is deleted from memory.

Always be cautious when using it. It can save you from memory leaks only as far as your design is good to accomodate them.

For example I faced one issue.

I'd a class with map containing shared_ptrs. Later this class ( without my knowledge )was also made responsible for passing these shared-ptrs to some other classes which in-turn used some containers to store these. As a result this code blowed up luckily on tester's face in the form of memory leak.

I hope you can figure out why.

Comment: I don't think I am sure why. Wouldn't the object the shared_ptr stores stay allocated while all the classes exist and be deallocated when all the classes get destroyed?